# Maximize my odds

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence 'that would *maximize my odds* of being right' in context of

> “To make money in the markets, one needs to be an independent thinker who bets against the consensus and is right. That’s because the consensus view is baked into the price. One is inevitably going to be painfully wrong a lot, so knowing how to do that well is critical to one’s success. To be a successful entrepreneur, the same is true: One also has to be an independent thinker who correctly bets against the consensus, which means being painfully wrong a fair amount. Since I was both an investor and an entrepreneur, I developed a healthy fear of being wrong and figured out an approach to decision making that would **maximize my odds of being right**.”

I looked up several dictionaries without finding the phrase 'maximize one's odd'

Does `my odds` mean `my opportunities of being odd`,so it can be rewrited as

> maximize my oppotunities of being odd of being right.

Comment: Did you check the word [_odds_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/odds)? Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you `http://www.dictionary.com/` is better off. I just checked word 'odd'  @Max

Comment: "that would maximize my *chances* of being right." It's like odds in betting.

Comment: "Odds" means "probabilities", usually related to some sort of gambling.